# What is significance of cud (compilation unit data) array value?

Tags: c++, oracle

What is significance of  (compilation unit ) array value?

How to decide what value my program is required?

I am using Linux 5 and Oracle 11g.

Please explain the below:

```
/*  (compilation unit ) array */
static const short sql0[] =
{12,4130,1,0,0,
5,0,0,1,0,0,273,111,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,
24,0,0,2,0,0,273,136,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,
43,0,0,3,0,0,273,161,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,
62,0,0,4,0,0,273,184,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,
81,0,0,5,0,0,273,212,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,
100,0,0,6,0,0,273,238,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,
119,0,0,7,0,0,273,262,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,
138,0,0,1,0,0,301,302,0,0,2,2,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,1,9,0,0,
161,0,0,1,0,0,269,306,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2,9,0,0,
180,0,0,2,0,0,301,343,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,
199,0,0,2,0,0,269,348,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,2,9,0,0,2,9,0,0,
222,0,0,3,0,0,277,394,0,0,2,2,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,1,9,0,0,
245,0,0,3,0,0,277,419,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,
264,0,0,5,0,0,277,455,0,0,3,3,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,1,9,0,0,1,9,0,0,
291,0,0,6,0,0,277,493,0,0,3,3,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,1,9,0,0,1,9,0,0,
318,0,0,7,0,0,301,524,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,
337,0,0,7,0,0,269,525,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2,9,0,0,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment is only stating that the array has internal linkage (`static` in this context means internal linkage), which means that it is a only accessible in the current translation (compilation) unit. Which is kind of obvioous from the definition, but I guess that it means to make it explicit that it is intentional. It is a comment, so it has no meaning for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I'm proud of my analysis on the Oracle CUD and haven't been able to show it off much!

The CUD is a big array of integers that describe various aspects of the embedded SQL statements in a file compiled with Pro*C. Through experimentation I have made educated guesses on the structure of this data and how it is used. Keep in mind I have done my research on Solaris with Oracle 11, and the CUD data I have worked with looks slightly different than what you have here, so the position of the data values are likely different. Here's a random line from your data:

138,0,0,1,0,0,301,302,0,0,2,2,0,1,0,1,9,0,0,1,9,0,0,

Each line of the CUD (aside from the first 6 values) starts with a global offset. In this case it's 138 (index 0). The first 1 (index 3) likely represents the type of query (select, fetch, open cursor, close cursor, connect, etc). The 301 (index 6) is most likely the length of the query statement string itself. The 302 (index 7) refers to the pragma statements that Pro*C inserts in the code. On my system I would search for "#line 302 " in my code to see the query for this row of the CUD. Index 10 refers to how many bind variables are associated with this query (in this case only 2). The data for the bind variables themselves starts at index 15, and each variable has 4 data elements (both in this case having 1,9,0,0). The first of these values determines how the bind varibale is being used. A value of 1 means that the variable is used in the where clause. A 2 means a variable being selected/fetched into. The second value (9 in this case) refers to the type of variable (integer, char, etc).

I decided to learn this info about the CUD so I could put in some custom logging code that would output queries in my application as they were occurring.